# How to set desired time interval and in desired format for X-Axis in line chart Python Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

input data Csv:[Csv data][1]

Need some help to correct below part of the code.

plt.xticks.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))   #to get a tick every 15 minutes
plt.xticks.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%H:%M'))     #optional formatting

Code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv("Data 8199 2391 6_6_2019 13_39_02.csv",sep="\t",skiprows=68,encoding = "utf-16",index_col=0)


#plt.xticks.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))   #to get a tick every 15 minutes
#plt.xticks.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%H:%M'))     #optional formatting 
plt.yticks(np.arange(20, dfMax, step=5)) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey. Could you provide a subset (or a mockup) of your data so that your code is reproducible ? Also, if you added an image of the result you are trying to achieve (using an image editor for example), it would help.

Comment: @Lescurel, Updated requested details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `set_major_formatter` and `set_major_locator` are methods of an object `Axis`. In order to get the axes of the current figure, you can use the function [`plt.gca()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html).

---

So, you could use the following code :

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('D%d-%H:%M'))
```

resulting in the following image :

[image]

(I used `plt.xticks(rotation=30)` in order to have the label slightly rotated.)

Comment: Can you please help me with setting up Minor Axis with interval 1 for both axis?

Comment: @OO7 If you ask a new question, with a minimal reproducible example, and the result you want to achieve, I might be able to help.

Comment: Asked new as per request.         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984157/how-to-enable-minor-tick-minor-grid-and-xticks-for-matplotlib

Comment: Pls help me with above question.